# Visual Studio 2017 not start debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2017 on windows 7 for the development of a C# application, without modifying visual studio settings from now on I did not started debugging any project, how can I solve this?

**Compiling Output:**

```
'Myapp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Myapp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\Myapp\src\Myapp\Myapp\bin\Debug\Myapp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Myapp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Myapp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Myapp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Myapp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Myapp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Myapp.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[6700] Myapp.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6700] Myapp.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What happens when you press F5? Hope your project is compiling without errors.

Comment: @Habeeb I have output above.

Comment: It looks like it started and exited. not sure what is the problem.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Could it be that it thinks there is just nothing to do and exits immediately? Try setting a breakpoint of the very first line of code that should execute

Comment: Is a Windows Forms application. Now I try and let you know @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Tip: find the `Main` method, which probably is inside a `Program.cs` - this is the real starting point

Answer (score 0):

These are DLLs for which you don't have debug symbols for. Go to <kbd>Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols</kbd> and select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers", VS will download PDBs automatically.

For more detailed and better understanding of symbols, refer, [Understanding Symbol files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/)

Comment: I tried to do as you told me, but it does not change anything

Comment: PDB files, especially for system assemblies, are not required to *run* the application